# OR-Tools Python - AddNoOverlap2D not working - Stock Cutting Problem

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

Trying to cut given set of rectangles from a large rectangle. The program is running fine but it is not respecting the `AddNoOverlap2D` constraint.

The program outputs

```
0, 0 -> 2, 2
0, 0 -> 1, 3
0, 0 -> 4, 3
```

All the coordinates of rectangles output by program have `(0,0)` as first point and hence are overlaping. **I want get the rectangles that are not overlaping**?

I am using `model.AddNoOverlap2D` constraint and the objective I have set is to minimize the unused area of large rectangle. Complete Code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import collections
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

def StockCutter():
    """Cutting Stock problem."""
    # Create the model
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # rect = [width, height]
    rects_data = [
        [2, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [4, 3]
    ]

    rect_ids = range(len(rects_data))

    # parent rect (to cut from)
    horizon = [6, 6]
    print("Horizon: ", horizon)

    # Named tuple to store information about created variables
    rect_type = collections.namedtuple('rect_type', 'x1 y1 x2 y2 x_interval y_interval')

    all_vars = {}

    # to save area of all small rects, to cut from parent rect
    total_area = 0 

    # x_intervals holds the widths of each rect
    x_intervals = collections.defaultdict(list)
    # y_intervals holds the lengths of each rect
    y_intervals = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for rect_id, rect in enumerate(rects_data):
        width = rect[0]
        height = rect[1]
        area = width * height
        total_area += area
        print(f"Rect: {width}x{height}, Area: {area}")

        suffix = '_%i_%i' % (width, height)

        # interval to represent width
        x1_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon[0], 'x1' + suffix)
        x2_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon[0], 'x2' + suffix)
        x_interval_var = model.NewIntervalVar(x1_var, width, x2_var, 'x_interval' + suffix)

        # interval to represent height
        y1_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon[1], 'y1' + suffix)
        y2_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon[1], 'y2' + suffix)
        y_interval_var = model.NewIntervalVar(y1_var, height, y2_var, 'y_interval' + suffix)

        all_vars[rect_id] = rect_type(
            x1=x1_var, 
            y1=y1_var, 
            x2=x2_var, 
            y2=y2_var, 
            x_interval=x_interval_var,
            y_interval=y_interval_var
        )

        x_intervals[rect_id].append(x_interval_var)
        y_intervals[rect_id].append(y_interval_var)


    # NOT WORKING???
    for rect_id in rect_ids:
        model.AddNoOverlap2D(x_intervals[rect_id], y_intervals[rect_id])

    # objective: Area of parent (horizon) is max that the sum of all the rectangles' areas can have
    obj_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon[0]*horizon[1], 'area')

    # minimize the area not used
    model.Minimize(obj_var - total_area)

    # Solve model
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    status = solver.Solve(model)

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:

        # print coords
        for rect_id, rect in enumerate(rects_data):
            x1=solver.Value(all_vars[rect_id].x1)
            y1=solver.Value(all_vars[rect_id].y1)
            x2=solver.Value(all_vars[rect_id].x2)
            y2=solver.Value(all_vars[rect_id].y2)
            print(f"{x1}, {y1} -> {x2}, {y2}")

StockCutter()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only call AddNoOverlap2D once with the list of x_intervals and y_intervals:

```py
# x_intervals holds the widths of each rect
x_intervals = []
# y_intervals holds the lengths of each rect
y_intervals = []

for rect_id, rect in enumerate(rects_data):
    ...
    x_intervals.append(x_interval_var)
    y_intervals.append(y_interval_var)

model.AddNoOverlap2D(x_intervals, y_intervals)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stradivari. Can you please also tell how should I print multiple different solutions of this problem?

Comment: First, remove your objective as it isn't really doing anything and https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#all_solutions

Comment: Just found this thread and was wondering if someone extended the approach to the case where we can have several parent rectangular to cut from (so "several knapsacks" to distribute the rects onto)?